# Chrome.identity.getAuthToken not showing Google user list

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, identity

**content.js** This is the content page for chrome extension

```
document.getElementById("signIn").addEventListener("click", function(){
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({task:"switchUser", user: current_user},function(response){                     
    });
});
```

**background.js** This is the background page for chrome extension

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse){
   if(request.task == "switchUser"){
    function getToken(){
       chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function(token) { 
        sendResponse(token);
      });
    }
      chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({ token: 
       currentSessionAccessToken }, getToken);
    }
  return true;
});
```

Previous OAuth token is successfully removed but when generating a new one using getAuthToken, the user selection list is not shown. However, I have set interactive to true. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to revoke the token first and then remove from cache. Please find the code below for **background.js** page.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse){
if(request.task == "switchUser"){
function getToken(){
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function(token) { 
         sendResponse(token);
       });
     }
       var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlHttp.open('GET', 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' + currentSessionAccessToken); //revoke the token calling this url.
       xmlHttp.onload = function() { 
       chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({ token: currentSessionAccessToken }, getToken); //after token is revoked, remove it from cache as well.
     }
       xmlHttp.onerror = function(){             
      };
      xmlHttp.send();
    }
   return true;
 });
```